# Errno 5 Input/output error in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 in VMWare but while on the middle of copying files, a pop-up error would appear:

The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

```
[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may 
help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD 
drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check 
whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a 
cooler environment.
```

I have tried several times but the same thing happened. I even download again a copy still the same problem occurs.

I tried previous versions, 12.10 & 12.04. They worked fine.

I have searched and read several posts like this; none of provide solution.

Please help. What should I do?

Comment: check the output of `dmesg` for details.

Comment: Have you tried installing from USB?

Comment: Thanks for replies, however, I've already resolved this issue. What I did was I downloaded again a copy of Ubuntu through torrent. It worked fine as opposed to direct downloads.

Answer (score 0):

The OP [solved the problem and reported the solution in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292336/errno-5-input-output-error-in-ubuntu-13-04#comment376040_292336):

> I've already resolved this issue. What I did was I downloaded again a
>   copy of Ubuntu through torrent. It worked fine as opposed to direct
>   downloads.