# Install on Acer Aspire 4752

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, acer, aspire

I am at my wits end with this computer.  I bought and Acer Aspire 4752 with a fully loaded version of Windows 7 on it.   I prefer Ubuntu so I began to install 14.04 from USB.
Got the error:
[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may 
help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD 
drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check 
whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a 
cooler environment.

So I tried a different USB stick, same error.  Tried different versions of Ubuntu, got the same error.  I've used startup disk creator and Unetbootin to make start USB boot devices.

I can boot with the USB drive and run Ubuntu that way.  I even checked the hard drive using the tools in Ubuntu.  Everything was fine, except it said the hard drive was hot.  I tried a different hard drive.  Got same error above.   I ran a test with mem86, everything was fine.  No matter what I do, using the USB gives me the Errno5 error.

I then switched to using DVDs.   Now I keep getting an uncompression error when installing Ubuntu 14.04 or 12.04.

I can't figure out for the life of me why I get nothing but errors.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Had the same issue. Gave in and checked for defects which it found in 3 files, I'll try shoving it on a diff USB, if it fails 1 more time, then I know it's the ISO at fault. Edit: now says there's an error in 1 file. I'll try to install and see if it works.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Acer Aspire 4830tg, with a newly purchased Samsung SSD 840 Evo. Is it an Acer issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

May be and ACPI Problem. Can you disable the ACPI in the bios and try once again. Or go to the boot menu and edit kernel parameters and add acpi=off then try install 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
On an acer Timeline X 4830TG-6450 laptop installing Ubuntu 14.04

Note: I have had this exact same issue every time I try a fresh install starting from 13.04. However for the latter and 13.10, it worked when I used the .iso file downloaded via torrent as opposed to directly from the ubuntu servers, as also by user156627 on this thread: [Errno 5 Input/output error in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292336/errno-5-input-output-error-in-ubuntu-13-04)

With 14.04 the torrent file does not work as well and I'm stuck at the same stage.

Edit: Upon rechecking the MD5Sum, turns out the torrent file I had downloaded did not match the one stated on the ubuntu website.
I downloaded another .iso file from the website and it worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this on my own.  I just created a new start up disk from a different computer and everything installed without a problem.

I ran Ubuntu 14.04 without a problem for a month, then suddenly my task bar disappeared and I can't access terminal via ctrl-alt-t.   I reinstalled with Ubuntu Gnome (no unity) it worked for a day then the same problem came back.    Honestly, I think it's ACER.   I had a huge problem with Ubuntu and ACER a few years ago and swore off ACER until last month when I tried to give it another go.   This is the last ACER I will ever buy.   Too many headaches.

Comment: Did you download another iso on that different computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had spent four days trying to install Ubuntu, but was getting the same error.
 I finally went to the BIOS (<kbd>F2</kbd> just after powering on) before installing Ubuntu, and **disabled EFI**. And then I went on installing, and I no longer have that error. Now it works like a charm.